# UpdatePanel Repeater ObjectDataSource getting Error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel, asprepeater

I have developed an application in which I have used a UpdatePanel, Repeater and ObjectDataSource.

The problem is when I was using this three then I am getting a error like 
**"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation."**

**the prob is only occred in IE8 and not cought in local I mean my local machine in IE8 it's working fine but when I host the application on IIS then IE8 created a prob remaing all browser all things working fine.**

the code mentioned below

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdnKey" Value="mainAlt" />

        <qfx:label runat="server" ID="Label1" CssClass="subHeading" Text="term_Shares"></qfx:label>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptShareTypeList"  runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="shareItem">
                <span class="shareItemButton"></span>
                <span class="shareItemLabel">
                <%#IRAppMgr.Translate(Convert.ToString(Eval("title"))) %>
                <input style="display: none" class="ShareTypeCheckBox" type="checkbox" name='<%#  Eval("key")  %>' value="<%#Eval("Code") %>" <%# Eval("checked12") %> />
                <input class="ShareColor" type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("Color") %>" />
                <input class="ShareCurrency" type="hidden" value="<%#Eval("Currency") %>" />
                </span>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
       <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="SharesTypeDS" runat="server" DataObjectTypeName="Qfx.DataClasses.Config.Option"
            SelectMethod="SelectShareType" TypeName="Qfx.Bases.data.DataManager">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClientMarker" Name="appConfig" PropertyName="Config"
                    Type="Object" />
                <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClientMarker" Name="client" PropertyName="Client" />
                <asp:Parameter Name="selection" DefaultValue="ShareType" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

**above mentioned code in my InstrumentSelectionBox.ascx control**

in my Qfx.Bases.data.DataManager class

```
public List<Option> SelectShareType(object appConfig, string client, string selection, string ShareKey)
    {
        AppConfig config = (AppConfig)appConfig;
        List<Option> Options = null;
        if (config.getSelectionByKey(ShareKey + selection) != null)
            Options = config.getSelectionByKey(ShareKey + selection).Options;
        if (Options != null && Options.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (Option option in Options)
            {
                if (option.Currency == null && IRAppManager.Manager != null)
                {
                    DataClasses.Share.Instrument inst = IRAppManager.Manager.GetInstrument(option.Key);
                    option.Currency = (inst != null) ? IRAppManager.Manager.Translate(inst.Currency) : "";
                }
                if (option.VolumeDivisor == null || option.VolumeDivisor.Trim() == string.Empty)
                    option.VolumeDivisor = option.VolumeValue;
                option.Code = (config.GetDataSourceByKey(option.Key) != null) ? config.GetDataSourceByKey(option.Key).Code : "";
                if (option.Code != string.Empty)
                {
                    option.TimeStamp = GetTimeStampDetail(option.Code);
                }
            }
        }
        return (config.getSelectionByKey(ShareKey + selection) != null) ? config.getSelectionByKey(ShareKey + selection).Options : new List<Option>();
    }
```

and I have used that in Updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTab" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <uc:InstrumentSelectionBoxrunat="server" ID="UTCInstrumentSelectionBox"></uc:InstrumentSelectionBoxrunat>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

after some debugging in browser console I thought due to ObjectDataSource the errors occured so what I did I have removed the ObjectDataSource and bind the repeater normal with Id then It's working fine in IE8.

so can anyone plese help me is there any restriction in IE8 while using ObjectDataSource or my code has error.
your respone should highly appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[*ObjectDataSource*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectmethod%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) use reflection in order to call the function/method. Your method in special case might be giving an exception. Here is the [reference thread](http://forums.asp.net/t/1545490.aspx?Sys+WebForms+PageRequestManagerServerErrorException+Exception+has+been+thrown+by+the+target+of+an+invocation), please go through and debug your method.

Comment: I have tested it the application not working only IE8 do I need to add any meta tag for it.

Comment: Did you debug your method, isn't there any exception/innerexception anywhere in the call.

Comment: Yes I have Debug it and at one place I am getting error like Object reference not set to an instance of an object in IE8 while not getting in other browser

Comment: can you please set *EnableCaching=True*, i am not sure but this has something to do with either caching or UpdatePanel. please give it a try.

Comment: Hey Hie Thanks for your help it's resolved now due to one js it caused the prob

Comment: if my answer helped you fully, please upvote & accept it as its authenticated then. otherwise please share your your solution. thanks & happy coding : )